# Class function inside a component while running ngFor gives Error (not a function)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to show a list of *topics* where every list entry is a custom component.
I will describe my problem as a simple example of my code.

*Using the current (02/2020) Version of Angular, MongoDB and Chrome*

**Topic class:**

```ts
export class Topic {
    constructor(
        public title: string,
        public solutionID: number[] = [],
        private rating: number = 0,
        private votes: number = 0
    ) { }

    currentRating(): number {
        return this.rating / this.votes;
    }

    vote(stars: number) {
        this.votes++;
        this.rating += stars;
    }


    lastEditDate(): Date {
        console.log('test');
        return this.ts_worker[this.ts_worker.length - 1];
    }
}
```

**main-view.component.html** This is the "frame" where the list is shown

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <app-topic-view *ngFor="let tp of topics" [topic]="tp"></app-topic-view>
</div>
```

**main-view.component.ts** This is where my topics come from (GET from Server)

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TopicsService } from 'src/app/services/topics.service';
import { Topic } from 'src/app/classes/class_Topic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-view',
  templateUrl: './main-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-view.component.scss']
})

export class MainViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() topics: Topic[];

  constructor(private topicService: TopicsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.topicService.getAllTopics().subscribe((topics: Topic[]) => {
      this.topics = topics;
    })
  }

}
```

**topic-view.component.html**

```html
<div class="topicElement">
    <!-- Some code hidden here -->
    <div class="back-group">
        <div class="solutionCount">Solutions: {{(topic.ts_worker[topic.ts_worker.length - 1])}}</div>
        <div class="solutionCount">Solutions: {{(topic.lastEditDate())}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error is found in `{{(topic.lastEditDate()}}`.

***The line above that works just fine. Only the function call doesn't work.***

**Error**
[image: Image of Error "lastEditDate is not a function"]

**Goal**
[image: How it looks renderes]

---

*What am I missing here*

In the end I would like to use the functions of my class. I'm used to do this in other languages.
Is this possible in Angular?

*EDIT: Typo fixed*

Comment: Could you be missing a closing ")" here:

<div class="solutionCount">Solutions: {{(topic.lastEditDate()}}</div>

Comment: Here is the issue `{{(topic.lastEditDate()}}` just after the open interpolation brackets you have an open braket `(` which is creating the problem as  there isn't a closing one.

Comment: TYPO, while I made the code short for Stackoverflow ... sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "topics" are not class Topic when return of the http because when it's traspile to javaScript, you only has an object, you need create as

```
 this.topicService.getAllTopics().subscribe((topics: Topic[]) => {
      this.topics=x.map(x=>new Topic(x.title,x.solutionID,x.rating,x.votes))
    })
```

Others idea is that Topic was

```
export class Topic {
  public title;
  public solutionID;
  private rating;
  private votes;
  constructor({ title, solutionID, rating, votes }) {
    this.title = title;
    this.solutionID = solutionID;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.votes = votes;
  }
  ..your methods...
}
```

And write

```
this.topicService.getAllTopics().subscribe((topics: Topic[]) => {
      this.topics=x.map(x=>new Topic(x))
    })
```

And another idea are that in your app-topic-view you has

```
private _topic:Topic
@Input() set topic(value)
{
  this._topic=new Topic(value.title,value.solutionID,value.rating,value.votes)
  //or if you change the constructor
  // this._topic=new Topic(value);
}

get topic()
{
     return this._topic;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, true. Missed that. Thanks for clarifying. Will delete my answer then :) Good find!

Comment: With the new constructor, can i use optional fields with a given value, when i create a `new Topic()`?

Comment: The constructor make use of object destructuring: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring, in a function you can asign default values too http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#function-declarations

Comment: With `this.topicService.getAllTopics().subscribe((x: Topic[]) => {
      this.topics=x.map(x=>new Topic(x))
    })` I get an **Error**: `Topic` not assignable to parameter type, because `rating` is private in type `Topic` but not in the type of the constructor. Please advise =)

Comment: Diego, this only works with the new constructor of Topic `constructor({ title, solutionID, rating, votes }) `

Comment: Yes, I already changed the constructor, too. `constructor({ title, solutionID, rating = 0, votes = 0 }) { /* all the this.XXX = XXX; */ }` This is why i don't understand the error.